# how to remove elements from array in firestore with a where clause in python

Tags: python, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've a sample collection in my firestore
[image]

I've got two arrays in a document. I want to delete the whole array dictionary from two arrays if monthName is January.

Desired output
[image]

I've tried

```
doc_ref = db.collection('calender').where('monthName', 'array_contains', 'January').arrayremove()
```

But I'm getting an error

```
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'arrayRemove'
```

I referred the documentation, but I couldn't understand that to this problem. So, looking for help here.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore doesn't have the concept of an update query, where you send a condition and an operation to the database. You'll instead have to:

1. Execute the query to get all documents matching your condition.
2. Loop over the documents in your Python code.
3. Then remove the array from each document with an update call.

---

In addition, `arrayRemove` can only be used if you know the exact, complete item to remove from the array, you will have to:

1. Load the document (same as above).
2. Get the array, and remove the item.
3. Write the entire remaining array back to the database.

Comment: So there is no way to update/delete from array as mentioned above?

Comment: That is indeed not possible. I added some more info to my answer.

Comment: Can you please provide me a snippet of your explanation? It would be easy to understand

Comment: I recommend having a look at these, as the question on how to remove items from an array pops up regularly: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+remove+item+from+array

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [firestore index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) to query for documents without knowing their IDs. If you create an index on `calender` on the fields `month1` and `month2`, your `CollectionGroup` query would run successfully with (in pseudocode):

```
objectToDelete = {id: 1, monthName: "January"}

for month in ["month1", "month2"]:
  matchingDocRefs = db.collection("calender")
                   .where(month, "array-contains", objectToDelete)
                   .get() // Returns a list of matching DocumentReferences
  for documentRef in matchingDocRefs:
      documentRef.update({ month, firestore.ArrayRemove(objectToDelete)})
```

Tested and working in JavaScript.

REFERENCES:

- [Firestore queries on array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) (click "Python" tab)
- [Removing elements from an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) (click "Python" tab)
- [Python Document object documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html)

P.S., it's spelled "calend**a**r", not "calend**e**r"